# Is there a way to generate a unique random 6 digit number?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Is there a way using vb.net to generate a random 6 digit number that is unique? So there are no duplicate random numbers?

I tried the following code  but it says "Type Char has no contructors"

```
Dim chars As String = "0123456789"
Dim word As Char() = New Char(6)
Dim rnd As New Random()
For i As Integer = 0 To word.Length - 1
word(i) = chars.Chars(rnd.Next(chars.Length))
Next
TheTextBox.Text = New String(word)
```

Comment: Unique in a set? Unique in a period of time? Unique... how?

Comment: This will be for at least a couple years with a maybe up to 15,000 records

Comment: @BradChristie: never heard of uppercasing or lowercasing digits ;)

Comment: @WiktorZychla: it's that 2'o'clock feeling apparently. I saw this as a 6-character hash. Oops. ;p EDIT: To answer your question: 0=lower,O=Upper;1=lower,I=Upper. ;-)

Comment: you aren't creating a unique identifier are you?  like to store as an identity field in a database?

Comment: I am but I can use that because multiple records need this unique ID

Comment: I tried the following code above  but it says "Type Char has no contructors"

Comment: Why does it need to be random and unique? Can it just be unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try..

```
Dim randomNumber As Integer

Randomize() 

randomNumber = Int((100000* Rnd()) + 1) 

MsgBox(randomNumber)
```

Comment: This, of course, is not guaranteed to be unique.

Answer (score 6):

Wouldn't this do? Meaning increment the `number` for each record or whatever it's used for. Guarantees unique.

```
Dim number as integer = 100000
'do stuff
number +=1
```

Comment: lol, why downvote? it IS a valid answer to this incredibly general question.

Comment: ha - Alternate implementation:
`Dim number as Integer = 999999
'do stuff
number -= 1`

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd use a Linear Feedback Shift Register with 20 bits.  That's 1,048,575 different values instead of exactly 1000000, but hopefully close enough.

Just remember to keep the current seed value around between runs if you want to maintain uniqueness!

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_feedback_shift_register